# Is there a way to electronically protect a device from bad chargers?

Tags: battery-charging

In a discussion with a colleage, he claimed that with simple electronics you can protect a device from fake, bad or even malicious chargers.

I do not have a deep understanding in electronics, but I’m interested in whether this is true, and the cynical claim that the only reason Apple puts recognition chips in their cables and chargers is just to make more money - is true.

I’m sure if it was so simple then every device manufacturer would have done it, and Note devices wouldn’t have exploded...

Any insight will be appreciated!

—
Clarification: I have nothing against the Note 7 (except, well, it exploded), it was just an example and indeed I did not look up the exact source of the problem. This is also not an “Apple vs. The World” issue, but just simple curiosity!

Comment: Recognition chips? In chargers?

Comment: Simple economics is much easier. Don't buy bad chargers!

Comment: *Apple puts recognition chips in their cables and chargers is just to make more money* Apple's story is: "to give the best customer experience" Indeed some of their cables have electronics. Very likely their mains adapters also have some form of identification. Apple is not the only one. HP and Dell also have this is their (business) laptops. The laptops will not run but not charge from an unidentified mains adapter.

Comment: A lithium cell protection chip looks simple until you look inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*with simple electronics you can protect a device from fake, bad or even malicious chargers.*

For sure that is possible. Up to a certain limit of course. The main properties of a charger are the **voltage** it supplies and how much **current** it can deliver while maintaining the voltage.

If the voltage is too low, then charging cannot and will not happen as the current will not flow through the charge controller (inside the phone) into the battery.

If the voltage is a bit too high it is not a major problem, usually the normal circuits can take care of that already.

For voltages above what the normal circuitry can take care of you do need extra protection measures. There are several solutions for this including (non)recoverable fuses. It all depends on how far you want to go, how much money you're willing to spend on this protection.

And regarding the current from the charger, the only issue is when it cannot deliver enough current but then charging will simply take longer or stop altogether.

As Passerby mentioned, the Note 7 debacle had **nothing** to do with the charger or using "3rd party" chargers. It was Samsung's marketing/management department(s) wanting to squeeze in a **large** battery in a space that is **too small** for that battery so that the battery did not have any "breathing space". The engineers must have known that these batteries **need** that "breathing space", as that is **common knowledge**. Source for this: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_7)

Comment: As I commented on Passerby's answer, the problem of note 7 was not likely due to the battery (the supplier was changed and the problem was still there). But to the note 7 internal charging circuitry (probably due to overheat, it allowed the battery to be overcharged).

Comment: @next-hack I disagree: read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_7  that: *after it was found that a manufacturing defect in the phones' batteries had caused some of them to generate excessive heat, resulting in fires*  It says **nothing** about the charging circuitry. The excessive heat is the result of the battery not having enough room for expanding in size (which is normal) whereupon the anode and cathode **touch** causing a **short circuit** inside the battery. Further down on that Wikipedia page under "Battery faults" there's more.

Comment: Also note how the refurbished Note7 has a **smaller capacity battery**.

Comment: Maybe, but if I were a company selling phones, I would blame the provider of components, rather my bad design of internal charging circuitry. **In the same wiki page**: Samsung exchanged the affected phones for a new revision, which utilized **batteries sourced from a different supplier**. However, after reports emerged of incidents where these **replacement phones also caught on fire**, Samsung recalled the Galaxy Note 7 worldwide on 10 October 2016, and permanently ceased production of the device on 11 October.

Comment: Of course Samsung blamed the battery manufacturer(s)! Again you talk about the charging circuitry, you should show **evidence** that it indeed was the charging circuitry. Fact: Li-Polymer batteries expand/contract in size a little bit when charged/discharged. Fact: when expanding in too small space, separation between anode and cathode can be compromised resulting in a short circuit causing fire/explosion. Fact: the refurbished (recalled, updated) Note 7 has a **smaller** battery.

Comment: I agree with you that the final explosion was likely due to the shortcircuit, possibly due to the lack of space and insulation. However I agree with McPherson, that this was triggered by the battery charging/monitor/protection circuitry, that likely drifted too much on some units, with temperature (overcharging the battery). By the way: I would not count as reliable engineering sources such sites like "The Verge" or "The Guardian"...

Comment: I am still unconvinced that the battery charging circuit is at fault here. "drifted too much" is just an **assumption**. Fact is that battery charging ICs are quite accurate (within a few %). If McPherson has no (fact based) idea what the problem was then he should not say anything **or** emphasize that it is **his** assumption. People like him are expected to present the facts and not make rogue assumptions without proof. Words like "it was probably" and "very likely..." should tell you enough that what he was saying should be taken with a pinch of salt. If there is proof he should show it.

Comment: You're missing that: 1) The faulty cases were quite low, compared to the number of devices sold 2) This is comparable with faulty ICs 3) There is a tendendcy of squeezing more and more charge. Anyway, a good reading: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-981-10-3290-5_20 .

Comment: 1) this proves nothing 2) also proves nothing: counterproof: all ICs are tested before they leave the factory. There is **no proof** that the charging ICs are at fault. The only evidence you bring up is circumstantial. 3) actually proves my point, how do they increase the capacity? By making the separators thinner. This increases the chances of a short circuit. Safety is all about **statistics**, you can **never** prove that something is 100% safe/reliable. Only **unsafety** can be proven. There is only "safe enough". Samsung took a gamble and lost with the Note 7.

Comment: The problem I have with the statements from McPherson is that he uses his authority and experience as proof for his claims (charging circuitry at fault). That's basically "Ad hominem" meaning: *I'm the expert, I say it so it is true. Because I'm the expert!* He should have known better than that. He should have proven his claims. He didn't and said that it was "likely" so basically he gave his **opinion**. That's OK but then that does not make it "the truth". Problem is, his audience (you @next-hack included) then believe him and assume what he says is the truth. But that remains unproven.

Comment: Of course neither I nor you have access to the intimate data of Samsung. We can just make conjectures. With "3" I was pointing that if you work closer to the breaking point, small deviations can bring you past it. This can be due to faulty IC (See reference).

ICs are factory tested, still you miss IC to IC parameter dispersion, and ESD strikes, which might cause latent damage (i.e. not immediately observed), which might be depassivated with subsequent stress.

By the way, the same references (indirectly cited by you through), shows that IC-induced overcharging might be a cause.

Comment: Yes many things **could** have happened to the ICs, however I find that unlikely because the same things can and will also happen to the ICs in other phones. Which do not have the Note7's problems.

Comment: You're forgetting iPhone 8 Plus :) (yes, they did not explode, because the battery ultimately did not short-circuit. That was the cause of the explosion on SGN7).

Comment: I don't care about the iPhone 8+, but since you bring it up, I think (opinion!) the Iphone 8+ proves my point. The battery can swell up. Luckily the Iphone just pushes out the display instead of catching fire. But again: rare events, which were not caught in product verification. Manufacturers are pushing the margins, seems they have reached the edge.

Comment: Opinion: I agree with you. But let's think about this: management circuitries have their gaussian dispersion (on their precision). Battery have gaussian dispersion (on their maximum charge above which they rupture/swell too much). Where is the fault? Maybe battery AND charging circuitry. (Ultimately: the engineer who pushed these two gaussian curves too close each other...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66868/discussion-between-bimpelrekkie-and-next-hack).

Answer (score 1):

First,  the Note phones failed due to heat and faulty batteries. Not just chargers.

Second, the way Apple originally did it is by using two steps. 1 is by current limiting the phone, with variable limits based on 2, ID signalling what type of charger is used. This was by arbitrary resistor voltage dividers for different current sourcing capacity. This prevented cheap 5V sources from working until everybody figured out what Apple did. Now, many phones have this same system. My s7 will only pull 450 mA from cheap 5V sources, .7 to 1 amp for basic, 2.1 for higher, and then we get into fast charging and newer signalling techniques that switch the charger into different voltages.

The phones also test for the right voltage. Too high or low and it will stop charging. Too noisy or too much ripple and it will stop too. There are power management ICs that will handle this for you.

Comment: I attended a reliability seminar of J.W. McPherson. He stated that the note 7's problem likely was not due to the battery - the problem was still present when they changed battery supplier. The problem was likely to the circuitry inside the phone, which lead, in some cases, to the overcharge of the battery.

Comment: Correction: J. McPherson!

Comment: Hmm, the Wikipedia page disagrees with him then. *the problem was still present when they changed battery supplier.* That does **not** prove that it is not the battery! In both cases (old batteries, new batteris) the battery has no room for expansion resulting in a short circuit. The conclusion that it then must be the charging circuit is (in my opinion) too quick. There is **no proof** that it was the charging circuit. -1 for This J. McPherson, next time he should get his facts right.